# How to calculate distance from point A to point B taking into account the availability of roads and public transport?

Tags: postgresql, gis, openstreetmap, postgis, opentripplanner

Imagine I have a PostGIS database with following pieces of information

1. OSM (OpenStreetMap) of a city,
2. the roads/streets inside the city and
3. the routes of public transport in that city.

I want

1. to calculate distance from building A to building B in that city **via streets/roads** (for people with cars) and
2. to estimate the amount of time it takes to get from building A to building B using available **public transport** (for people without a car).

Is there any ready-made (open source or commercial) software for performing such calculations in PostGIS?

Comment: This might be more successful on gis.stackexchange.com . Maybe ask a mod to migrate it?

Comment: Good idea. I asked the moderator to move the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For public transport planning you should check [OpenTripPlanner](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Demos), too. After the link, you will see various examples, not all works, but Athens does.

Comment: Great! Do you know the source of data about public transport used in those demos? Perhaps you know where I can get such data for Russian cities?

Comment: As I know, every case is different, so if you want to access the data, you should get from directly the transport company. :(
In some cases, these companies ensure access through GTFS (https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/).
You could find many data source for example here: http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [PgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) does exactly that. Here's an [intro](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/).